# Python JSON KeyError for key that is not missing in object being parsed

Tags: python, json, parsing, keyerror

I'm crawling and parsing the JSON data I'm getting from RiotGames LoL API using Python (2.X) and I'm running into an odd error.

I'm loading in the json data and reading the data attr by attr, which goes great until I hit a certain attr which is clearly in the object I'm trying to extract it from but makes Python throw a KeyError as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]
Here is the codesnippet where the error takes place. As you can see I print the object (for debugging purposes) and then parse all attr, which works fine but throws a KeyError for unknown reasons at the attr 'doubleKills'. Hope you guys can help ^^

```
def parseJSON(self, jsonDump):
    matchDetailDict =  dict()
    jsonobj = json.loads(jsonDump)

    matchId = jsonobj['matchId']
    tmpMatch = Match()
    tmpMatch.matchID = matchId

    tmpMatch.creationDate = jsonobj['matchCreation']
    tmpMatch.matchDuration = jsonobj['matchDuration']

    for participant, participantId in zip(jsonobj['participants'], jsonobj['participantIdentities']):
        stats = participant['stats']
        print stats
        tmpStats = MatchPlayerStats()
        tmpStats.playerID = participantId['player']['summonerId']
        tmpStats.matchID = matchId
        tmpStats.winner = stats['winner']
        tmpStats.kills = stats['kills']
        tmpStats.deaths = stats['deaths']
        tmpStats.assists = stats['assists']
        tmpStats.kda = (tmpStats.kills + tmpStats.assists)*1.0/max(tmpStats.deaths, 0.5) 
        tmpStats.visionWardsBoughtInGame = stats['visionWardsBoughtInGame']
        tmpStats.sightWardsBoughtInGame = stats['sightWardsBoughtInGame']
        tmpStats.championID = participant['championId']
        tmpStats.doubleKills = participant['doubleKills'] #KeyError here!
        tmpStats.firstBloodAssist = participant['firstBloodAssist']
        tmpStats.firstBloodKill = participant['firstBloodKill']
        tmpStats.killingSprees = participant['killingSprees']
        tmpStats.wardsKilled = participant['wardsKilled']
        tmpStats.wardsPlaced = participant['wardsPlaced']
        tmpStats.unrealKills = participant['unrealKills']

        matchDetailDict[tmpStats.playerID] = tmpStats

    tmpMatch.playerStats = matchDetailDict
    return tmpMatch
```

Comment: Wrap it in a `try: .. except KeyError: print list(participant)` - see what 's there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the JSON on the Terminal you posted is from `stats`, but you are trying to use the key on `participant`.

```
print 'doubleKills' in stats.keys()
```

Should evaluate to `True`

Comment: OMFG... I've been staring at the code for quite a while now.. How could I have NOT seen that.. Well sometimes all you  need is someone else evaluating your code I guess.. thanks you're right, it should have been stsats[key] ^_^

Comment: Happened to me on more than one occasion :D. Just like proof reading!